# get all image library lists via listdata.svc or web service, how?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I want to retrive all image/picture lists a site has with javascript. 
Can that be done via listdata.svc or via a soap webs service?
When looking at the response from listdata.svc i can't see what type each list is in the response, so to me it seems like listdata.svc cannot be used?
If so, which soap web service is it that i should use instead?

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to look at the GetListCollection operation of the Lists web service.  In the response there'll be a ServerTemplate field. In MOSS 2007, I see picture Libraries having a ServerTemplate of 109.

Comment: Agreed on the approach. If you want to do it client side, look at SPServices to help you out. [link](http://spservices.codeplex.com)

Comment: That works too, depends on how he wants to implement the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in SharePoint 2010, and using JavaScript, just use the ECMA Script Client Object Model.

Intro: [SharePoint 2010: Client Object Model for JavaScript (ECMAScript)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript.aspx).

Some info about the ListCollection class: [SP.ListCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410509.aspx).

This depends on your javascript competency. It does use Object Oriented Javascript which just scares the bejesus out of me (I'm a Server Object Model in C# & .NET Framework-loving cat), but it's another option for you.